# Drupal installation directory name change: Are there any consequences?

Tags: drupal

Are there any consequences if I installed Drupal into the "/drupal" directory, and then I change the directory name to "xyz"? I am using Drupal 7.8. If you know about version 6 as well I would like to hear it.

It's quite a fresh install, only 2-3 mimemail and  2 simplenews modules have been installed.
If it's problematic, will an alias hide the original folder name without problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that you will have to change is any Apache/IIS configuration that is pointing to that directory (document roots, virtual hosts, etc.). It may also be a good idea to clear the cache in case any of your installed modules are relying on that path.

Comment: nothing server related is pointing to the instalation at this point, so I guess it's safe in that case to just change it as far as drupal core itself (which is that interests me) is concerned. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If /drupal/ is the absolute path to Your vhost, no, there is no problem to change it.

Comment: is this comment for Alias only or for both? Thank you.